# Можно ли алгоритмы глубинного обучения рассматривать как ансамблевые методы?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-образов

Кратко о глубинном обучении согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

> **Глубинное обучение** (Deep learning) — набор алгоритмов машинного
>   обучения, которые пытаются моделировать высокоуровневые абстракции в
>   данных, используя архитектуры, состоящие из множества нелинейных
>   трансформаций.
>
> Под термином «*глубина*» в данном случае понимается глубина графа
>   вычислений модели — максимальная длина между входным и выходным узлами
>   конкретной архитектуры. В случае, например, простой нейронной сети
>   прямого распространения глубина соответствует **количеству слоев сети**.

---

### Вопрос:

Можно ли к примеру глубокие нейронные сети ([deep neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning#Deep_neural_network_architectures)) или  [сверточные нейронные сети](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) (convolutional deep neural networks) относить к ансамблевым алгоритмам машинного обучения ([ensemble learning methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning))?